# Async functions vs await

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

I'm coming from a PHP background and I'm trying to learn NodeJS.

I know that everything in Node is async but I've found that i've been using the async / await combo quite a lot in my code and I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something stupid.

The reason for it is that I have a lot of situations where I **need** the result of something before continuing (for example for a small ajax request). This small ajax request has no other purpose other than to do the set of things that I want it to and in the order that I specify so even if I do things the "async way" and write it using a callback i'm still having to wait for things to finish in the right order.

Right now whenever I find myself in this situation I just use await to wait for the result:

ie:

```
var result = await this.doSomething(data);
```

Opposed to using a callback

```
this.doSomething(data, function(callback) {
  // code
  callback();
});
```

To me the first example looks cleaner than the second one which is why I've been opting for that. But I'm worried that I might be missing something fundamental here. But in a situation where there is nothing else to process below the async call and the only way for things to progress is for it to follow a syncronous style, is there anything wrong with using the first style over the second?

Comment: *"I know that everything in Node is async..."* Not *everything*. :-)

Comment: the first way is newer. the second way is older.

Comment: You are right, the first way is cleaner, BUT you can only use `await` inside an async function. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I'm worried that I might be missing something fundamental here.

Nope, you're not, that's exactly what you want to do, assuming `this.doSomething(data)` is asynchronous (and if it's an ajax call, one hopes it is async) and that it returns a promise (which all functions defined with the `async` keyword do implicitly). (If it's not asynchronous, you don't need the `await`, although it's allowed.)

You're probably being a bit confused (understandably) by the fact that things are going through a transition. Until recently, the overwhelming convention in Node APIs (the built-in ones and ones provided by third-party modules) was to use the "Node callback" pattern, which is that a function that will do asynchronous work expects its last argument to be a callback, which it will call with a first argument indicating success/failure (`null` = success, anything else is an error object) with subsequent arguments providing the result. (Your second example assumes `doSomething` is one of these, instead of being a function that returns a promise.)

Example: `fs.readFile`, which you use like this:

```
fs.readFile("/some/file", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // ...handle the fact an error occurred..
        return;
    }
    // ...use the data...
});
```

This style quickly leads to callback hell, though, which is one of the reasons promises (aka "futures") were invented.

But a **lot** of Node APIs still use the old pattern.

If you need to use "Node callback"-pattern functions, you can use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create promise-enabled versions of them. For instance, say you need to use `fs.readFile`, which uses the Node callback pattern. You can get a promise version like this:

```
const readFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
```

...and then use it with `async`/`await` syntax (or use the promise directly via `then`):

```
const data = await readFilePromise("/some/file", "utf-8");
```

There's also an `npm` module called [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) that can provide a promise-ified version of an entire API. (There's probably more than one.)

Just because promises and `async`/`await` replace the old Node callback style in most cases doesn't mean callbacks don't still have a place: A Promise can only be settled **once**. They're for one-off things. So callbacks still have a place, such as with the `on` method of [EventEmitters](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), like a readable stream:

```
fs.createReadStream("/some/file", "utf-8")
    .on("data", chunk => {
        // ...do something with the chunk of data...
    })
    .on("end", () => {
        // ...do something with the fact the end of the stream was reached...
    });
```

Since `data` will fire multiple times, it makes sense to use a callback for it; a promise wouldn't apply.

Also note that you can only use `await` in an `async` function. Consequently, you may find yourself getting into the habit of a "main" module structure that looks something like this:

```
// ...Setup (`require` calls, `import` once it's supported, etc.)...
(async () => {
    // Code that can use `await `here...
})().catch(err => {
    // Handle the fact an error/promise rejection occurred in the top level of your code
});
```

You can leave the `catch` off if you want your script to terminate on an unhandled error/rejection. (Node doesn't do that yet, but it will once unhandled rejection detection matures.)

Alternately, if you want to use a promise-enabled function in a non-`async` function, just use `then` and `catch`:

```
this.doSomething()
    .then(result => {
        // Use result
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle error
    });
```

---

**Note**: `async`/`await` is directly supported in Node 7.x and above. Be sure your target production environment supports Node 7.x or above if your'e going to use `async`/`await`. If not, you could transpile your code using something like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) and then use the transpiled result on the older version of Node.

Comment: Promises are for events that only ever occur once. Callbacks should be used for those that occur multiple times.

Comment: @Crowes: Excellent observation, I'll work that in somehow. Most old-style Node API functions use callbacks for one-offs (other than EventEmitters, of course), but it's worth noting that callbacks still have a role.