# Chaining methods using promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to get my head around promises, I think I can see how they work in the way that you can say do `Step 1`, `Step 2` and then `Step 3` for example.
I have created this download function using `node-fetch` (which uses native Promises)

```
## FileDownload.js

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(url, target) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target);
      res.body.pipe(dest);
    }).then(function(){
      console.log(`File saved at ${target}`)
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
  });
}
```

So this all executes in order and I can see how that works.

I have another method that then converts a CSV file to JSON (again using a promise)

```
## CSVToJson.js

const csvjson = require('csvjson');
const fs = require('fs');
const write_file = require('../helpers/WriteToFile');

function csvToJson(csv_file, json_path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(csv_file, function(err, data){
      if (err)
        reject(err);
      else
        var data = data.toString();
        var options = {
          delimiter : ',',
          quote     : '"'
        };
      const json_data = csvjson.toObject(data, options);
      write_file(json_path, json_data)
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  csvToJson: csvToJson
}
```

When I call these functions one after another the second function fails as the first has not completed.

Do I need to wrap these two function calls inside another promise, even though on their own they each have promises implemented?

Please advise if I am totally misunderstanding this

Comment: you can `return` in your first exports function. that way it returns the promise so you can call another `then()` on it.

Comment: That first function incorrectly reports that the file is written, when in fact all you've done is set up the pipe. Setting up the pipe doesn't mean the file is written; the write process is asynchronous.

Comment: Your `csvToJson` function is missing critical `{` and `}` around the `else` logic, some of which is misleadingly indented, but only one part of which (`var data = data.toString();`) is actually attached to the `else`.

Comment: Also recommend deciding whether you're going to rely on automatic semicolon insertion or not, and then include (or leave out) `;` consistently. (Note that ASI is an *error correction mechanism**, which may influence your decision. Or not. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

> When I call these functions one after another the second function fails as the first has not completed.

There are two issues with the first:

1. It doesn't wait for the file to be written; all it does is set up the pipe, without waiting for the process to complete
2. It doesn't provide any way for the caller to know when the process is complete

To deal with the first issue, you have to wait for the `finish` event on the destination stream (which `pipe` returns). To deal with the second, you need to return a promise that won't be fulfilled until that happens. Something along these lines (see `**` comments):

```
module.exports = function(url, target) {
  // ** Return the end of the chain
  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(res) {
      // ** Unfortunately, `pipe` is not Promise-enabled, so we have to resort
      // to creating a promise here
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target);
        res.body.pipe(dest)
          .on('finish', () => resolve()) // ** Resolve on success
          .on('error', reject);          // ** Reject on error
      });
    }).then(result => {
      console.log(`File saved at ${target}`);
      return result;
    });
    // ** Don't `catch` here, let the caller handle it
}
```

Then you can use `then` and `catch` on the result to proceeed to the next step:

```
theFunctionAbove("/some/url", "some-target")
    .then(() = {
        // It worked, do the next thing
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // It failed
    });
```

(Or `async`/`await`.)

---

Side note: I haven't code-reviewed it, but a serious issue in `csvToJson` jumped out, a minor issue as well, and @Bergi has highlighted a second one:

1. It's missing `{` and `}` around the `else` logic
2. The minor issue is that you have `var data = data.toString();` but `data` was a parameter of that function, so the `var` is misleading (but harmless)
3. It doesn't properly handle errors in the part of the code in the `else` part of the `readFile` callback

We can fix both by doing a `resolve` in the `else` and performing the rest of the logic in a `then` handler:

```
function csvToJson(csv_file, json_path) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(csv_file, function(err, data){
      if (err)
        reject(err);
      else
        resolve(data);
    });
  })
  .then(data => {
    data = data.toString();
    var options = {
      delimiter : ',',
      quote     : '"'
    };
    const json_data = csvjson.toObject(data, options);
    write_file(json_path, json_data);
    return data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and answer, I will go through this now

Comment: if i wanted to chain further `then` and `catch` functions, can i add them on as you have done or would they become nested after the second function for example ? hopefully that makes sense

Comment: @Richlewis: If you wanted to do something else in `csvToJson` after the work that it currently does, you could certainly use `then` or `catch` on the promise we're creating there to do it.

Comment: @Richlewis: I should note that part of the reason some of the code above looks clunky is that it's mixing two worlds, the old Node callback style and promises. If you're going to move to using promises (which is a good idea), in general you're probably better served by getting to the promise stage *early* by wrapping the old-style functions like `fs.readFile` with promise-enabled versions, so that in most of your code you're only dealing with promise chains (or even `async`/`await`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47223222/157247) for more on doing that.

Comment: Even better suggestion than braces: put only `resolve(data)` in the `else`, and do the rest in a `then` callback where exceptions will be caught properly

Comment: Thanks, so i think i understand how to put together a method using a promise, what i am not quite understanding is say i have 3 methods `methodOne`, `methodTwo` and `MethodThree` and in a separate file i want to call them in order... how do i construct that? is it a new promise setup ?

Comment: @Richlewis: If they all return promises, and if `method2` needs the ouput of `method1`, and `method3` needs the output of `method1`, then: `obj.method1().then(r1 => obj.method2(r1)).then(result => obj.method3(r2)).catch(err => { /*...*/ });`

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer. am i correct in thinking that the function that uses `fetch` is supposed to return a Promise? as in when we resolve and return `result` that is a Promise. I only ask as it returns undefined at present, any chance of opening a quick chat please ?

Comment: @Richlewis: *"am i correct in thinking that the function that uses `fetch` is supposed to return a Promise?"* If you want it to provide a way for the caller to know when the work is done, yes. *"as in when we resolve and return `result` that is a Promise."* Well, `result` is a parameter in the final `then` callback which won't refer to a promise, but `then` returns a promise, and returning `result` from the `then` callback resolves that promise with `result`.